# API call to get Wikimedia Commons user's uploads with categories and wikitext

Tags: mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

How do I modify the example at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:API/MediaWiki#Get_files_uploaded_by_a_particular_user to also list the categories each page is
in, the wikitext of the page, and perhaps even some of the Structured Data?

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allimages&gaiuser=Jidanni&gaisort=timestamp&format=json&prop=categories gets files grouped by category. I want category grouped by file.

Comment: I could use steps, first getting the list, and then doing e.g., 
 https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Cape_Agamsik_Tanaga_Island_Alaska.jpg&action=raw on each one to get the wikitext (showing categories too) with no json too. Or if I like a json wrapper: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/page/File:Cape_Agamsik_Tanaga_Island_Alaska.jpg , but still only one at a time. I.e., 1 + 200 GETs. The first to get a list of the titles, then a separate call for each one.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm rather happy with:

```perl
$ cat Makefile
texts:wikitext list.json
    ./j2s $?|(cd $< && sh -ex)
wikitext:; mkdir $@
list.json: #https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allimages
    GET 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query$(\
    )&list=allimages&aiuser=Jidanni&aisort=timestamp$(\
    )&format=json&aiprop=url$(\
    )&aidir=descending&ailimit=4' > $@
$ cat j2s
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => q(all);    #old fashioned, yes
use JSON;
use open qw/:std :encoding(utf8)/;
my $j;
while (<>) { $j .= $_ }
my $p = decode_json $j;
for ( @{ $p->{query}->{allimages} } ) {
    my $f = $_->{name};
    if ( $f =~ /"/ ) {
        die "Oh man, even a double quote in my the proposed filename, $f.";
    }
    $f =~ s/\.jpg$/.txt/;
    printf "
if ! test -f \"%s\"
then wget --no-verbose --output-document \"%s\" \"%s%s\"; sleep 1
fi
", ($f) x 2, $_->{descriptionurl}, "?action=raw";
}
```

Note also https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API_talk:Main_page#Wikitext_of_all_matching_pages